# How to declare 2048 bit key in RSA

Tags: rsa

I want to implement RSA algorithm using C language. I have read the size of primes in RSA like p and q are
2048 bits long. How to declare such 2048 bit values in C. As i know that the data types like int , long ,long long int even are less than 64 bits. Please suggest.

Comment: You could use a bignum library (or just use an array of unsigned char's/int's/whatever, and implement the multiprecision math yourself, however that's rarely worth the effort).

Answer (score 1):

## 1. This is what you asked:

```
How to declare such 2048 bit values in C. As i know that the data types like int , long ,long long int even are less than 64 bits. Please suggest.
```

## 2. You can use the [The GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/).

[This is the manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/).

## 3 This is how to declare such 2048 bit values in C using `The GNU MP Bignum Library` .

```
// this is the big number p  
mpz_t p;       

// initialize  the big number p
mpz_inits (p, NULL);

// declaration or assignment of p 
mpz_set_str (p, "0x00ed6aead4012490897cc99074d534488d8cd85ecd0839fb6b1e12bd7a6a7849431a5aef1938e97b3cdeedfbd1166fa044c2785a1838bf1e71d88ff3009d1aac5f74756d1b3742e2931249e42b60f993d934df85d5bbd64e2dcb726e80a692b628f544549a15a4c85655c27a26ca144db403a27137fde1a9cdb8f46e8f677d1ecd", 0);
```

Comment: This is an example of use of GMP from C. It's a pragmatic solution to "I want to implement RSA algorithm using C language" using other people's code. In my view, it does not answer the question "How to declare 2048 bit key in RSA" in the C language. OTOH, if that question has to be asked, there is a lot of work ahead, and most of that work is off-topic.

Comment: I modify it. I think the question is that `How to declare 2048 bit key in RSA" in the C language.`, I give a method in C.  Please check it 。